# Pydev quick fix feature issue

Tags: pydev

To enjoy quick-fix feature of PyDev, I'm following nice video guideline from PyDev official website which is below.

http:// pydev.org / video_pydev_20.html

The question is my PyDev does not work as video shows (at the time of 00:55 of the video), which is quick fix to create Robot class by pressing Ctrl+1.

But, my context only shows "Move import to global scope". Do I miss something?

As I am pretty newbie at stackoverflow that I can't upload image here. :(

Capture from tutorial video, which I want to achieve.

http://i1142.photobucket.com/albums/n602/DearMyJohn/1.png

While below is my screenshot.

http://i1142.photobucket.com/albums/n602/DearMyJohn/2.png

I am using PyDev2.4.0 and Eclipse Indigo Service Release 1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The most common issue would be that your module is not in a source folder... There's a getting started guide at: http://pydev.org/manual_101_root.html which explains how to configure your source folders (which are the folders added to the PYTHONPATH).

It may also be that your file is beneath the PYTHONPATH but not under a python package (i.e.: a python package is a folder that has an `__init__.py` file in it) or your folder is not a valid python name (in which case it's also not treated as a package -- i.e.: folders with '.', '-', etc in the name).

Comment: Thanks very much Fabio. I always put my module under src folder because whenever I create pyDev project, I make "Create 'src' folder and add it to the PYTHONPATH?" option selected. For your second comment, I think I created valid python package name and have __init__.py file in it. Could you please have a look at [this link](http://i1142.photobucket.com/albums/n602/DearMyJohn/currentSetting.png) which illustrate current my pydev setting and folder structure? Did I miss something? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Your icons seem strange (usually in the PyDev package explorer they'd have different icons for source folders -- and for packages)... is this screenshot from the PyDev package explorer or from some other view? (if not, can you make a screenshot from the PyDev package explorer?)

Comment: Thank Fabio for your kind support. It's not actually captured from "PyDev Package Explorer" but "Navigator". Please check [this link](http://i1142.photobucket.com/albums/n602/DearMyJohn/pydevpackageExplorer.png) for screenshot from PyDev Package Explorer.

Comment: Do you have something in your error log? (see: http://pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-HowdoIReportaBUG%3F for details on getting the error log)

Answer (score 1):

You should have the cursor blinking on the line as in the first picture. Then it works. If you select even 1 character and press ctrl+1 then you get the situation in the second picture. I tested this in my setup which is the same as yours.

Comment: Thanks yilman for your comment. Actually I've tried both way before I posted here but had no luck. In my case, second picture is the result of when I have my cursor blinking on the line. Thanks anyway.